# ¿Como puedo hacer un select count para 3 tablas con el mismo ID?

Tags: base-de-datos

[image: Esas son mis tres tablas y el id que se repite]

Mi primera tabla se llama `tipoPension - cod_tipopension`, la segunda `reporte - cod_tipopension` y el tercero `dictamen - cod_tipopension`

Comment: investiga primero sobre  relacion y diseños entre tablas

Comment: Antes q nada, trata q tu pregunta sea entendible y prolija. No subas imagenes para mostrar algo tan simple. Y no uses mayusculas de mas (como en tu titulo). Te recomiendo que para la próxima leas [como elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: importante revisar [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes unir las 3 consultas en un solo resultado

```
(SELECT COUNT( cod_tipopension ) as 'Tipo pensión' FROM tipoPension)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT( cod_tipopension ) as 'Reporte' FROM reporte )
UNION
(SELECT COUNT( cod_tipopension ) as 'Dictamen' FROM dictamen )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola hay distintas maneras con un simple INNER U otra forma

```
Select  count(*) from(

consulta1

UNION ALL

consulta2

UNION ALL

consulta3 ) DATOS
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda, Saludos!!